# Passing .env consts to inner directories

Tags: javascript, typescript, environment-variables, knex.js

My ConfigKnex.ts file looks like

```
require("ts-node/register");
import { config } from "dotenv";
config();

const { DATABASE_URL } = process.env;
console.log({ DATABASE_URL });

export const development = {
    client: "postgresql",
    connection: DATABASE_URL,
};
```

My file directory looks like

```
server
- lib
-- somefiles.js
- package.json
- .env
```

If I run `"db:seed": "npx knex --knexfile ./ConfigKnex.ts seed:run"` , it works.

If I move ConfigKnex under the lib folder and run `"db:seed": "npx knex --knexfile ./lib/ConfigKnex.ts seed:run"`, it doesn't. Upon further debugging, I notice that the `DATABASE_URL` is undefined if I move ConfigKnex.

Why can ConfigKnex only get the .env if its local to itself? Is there a way to pass the .env consts to ConfigKnex without an in-between file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a path to dotenv.config(). Node's `path` module can resolve your issue and normalize the path. Something like this:

```js
import path from "path";
import { config } from "dotenv";
config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "..", ".env"), // adjust path to your needs
})
```